# Como enviar informacion dentro de la misma Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, formularios, validación

Tengo que hacer un formulario en la Activy (Princpial)una vez que se rellene los campos se haga click en Botón de Aceptar Política se vaya a otra Activity (Politica).
Se acepte en el checkBox de politica y al volver a la Activity (Principal) salga los datos introducidos anterior mente.

```
package com.example.formulario;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView recogidaDato;
    EditText nombre, edad;
    RadioGroup opciones;
    RadioButton php, java;
    String val;
    int numEdad;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recogidaDato = findViewById(R.id.tvRecogidaDatos);
        nombre = findViewById(R.id.etNombre);
        edad = findViewById(R.id.etEdad);
        opciones = findViewById(R.id.opciones);
        php = findViewById(R.id.radBtnPHP);
        java = findViewById(R.id.radBtnJAVA);


    }

    public void aceptar(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PoliticaPrivacidad.class);
        val = edad.getText().toString();
        numEdad = new Integer(val).intValue();

        if (nombre.toString().isEmpty() || edad.toString().isEmpty() || !(php.isChecked() || java.isChecked())) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Debe rellenar todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (numEdad < 18 || numEdad > 100) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "La edad tiene que estar entre 18 y 100", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            java.getText();
            php.getText();

            if (opciones.equals(java)) {
                i.putExtra("DATO", nombre + " con " + edad + " años ha elegido estudiar " + java);
            } else {
                i.putExtra("DATO", nombre + " con " + edad + " años ha elegido estudiar " + php);
            }

            String recogerDato = getIntent().getStringExtra("DATO");
            recogidaDato.setText(recogerDato);

            startActivity(i);

        }


    }
}
```

**Diseño**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Error**
No me marca un error como tal, simplemente no se refleja los datos en la Activity(Principal)

Comment: Cuando el programa se cierra, la consola debería mostrar qué falló. Deberías poner el error que da.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat?

Comment: Revisar el LogCat es muy importante, puede ser la diferencia en resolver un problema en un día o en unos segundos, agrega el mensaje de error que muestra el LogCat

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 2 actividades
**Actividad_1** --*ENVIA DATOS*-->  **Actividad_2**

Usas **PutExtra** para enviar de una actividad a otra, pero luego quieres mostrar esa informacion en la **Actividad_1**.
Podrias en lugar de usar una segunda actividad para las politicas usar un Dialogo personalizado con un boton de aceptar para guardar el dato que si acepto las politicas.
Otra opcion para tener acceso a los datos del proceso seria guardar en **SharedPreferences** y acceder a ellos cuando el usuario acepte las politicas.